# Centering Unordered List without styles

Tags: html

I have a ul in a table via html. I can center the ul by calling:

```
style="display:inline-table"
```

Is there a way to center the unordered list without using styles/css?

Full Code:

```
  <ul width="50%" align="left" style="display:inline-table" font-weight="normal">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li><font color="red">Note this list is left alligned but centered on the page</font></li>              
  </ul>
```

Comment: Why would you want to center it without style? Centering *is* a style; concerns should be separated, i.e. the markup should describe the content, and styles should be used to control the layout.

Comment: It's an assignment, the guy doesn't want any css or styles

Comment: To answer your question, no (short of using something completely obsolete). You should also validate your markup; `font` is deprecated,  `width` is not valid on a `ul`, and `font-weight` isn't a valid attribute.

Comment: Are you sure you have the assignment correct? you could style the document with an external stylesheet; no inline markup whatsoever. But no styles *at all* is impossible.

Comment: yea I know, I'm going to to ahead and just use the display=inline-table, his point is because he hasn't taught css or styles yet, he doesn't want anyone using them. Retarded I know.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Cth63/: use the `center` and `font` tags to create a centered, red warning across the screen that they are deprecated and link to the spec. In all seriousness, that's the wrong way to teach the concepts. But as long as *you* know that, no harm done I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this; centering *is* a form of styling. HTML simply defines the structure of a document and relies on styling for the rendering.

All browsers have a default stylesheet; if you don't provide one, the browser uses that stylesheet to determine how content should be rendered. Even if you *do* provide a stylesheet, the cascading nature of stylesheets mean that you're probably relying on at least one default CSS attribute on your page.

So, in short, you *have* to use styling.

Comment: yea that's what I thought, the professor doesn't want any css or styles within the tags, want's us to do it from scratch

Comment: Your professor *probably* wants you to use classes and IDs and CSS stylesheets, rather than style attributes and HTML presentational tags.

Comment: Yea originally I thought that to. He took points off my last assignment because I used classes and css. He's russian, I don't think he likes americans.

Comment: Are you able to share the text of the assignment? We might be able to infer what he's looking for more clearly from that.